# A case for GOTO

Tags: c++

First and foremost I want to say that I'm fully aware GOTO should normally be avoided in production code and it tends to be unreadable for others. For this specific case however, the code will not be read by anyone but me and the question is being asked mostly so I can understand what other options do I even have available since I lack experience with C++.

What the following code snippet does is it picks the best object from a queue based on a set amount of parameters. The parameters have different importance and the importance is reflected in the if statement nesting - the most important parameters and conditions are on the outside. The subsequent parameters are only used as tiebrakers in case the more important parameters match.

I also have not been able to find anything regarding this type of use for goto:

```
void class_method() {

    std::queue<int> my_queue;
    // generation of many objects happens here

    // Now I want to find the best element and I store the values for decider parameters
    // storing the object itself would be very inefficient as I care only about some key values
    int best_element_id = 0;
    int best_parameter_a = 0;
    int best_parameter_b = 0;
    // ...
    int best_parameter_z = 0;

    while (!my_queue.empty()) {
        if (my_queue.front().a_getter() > best_parameter_a) {
            // Found new best element since parameter A is most important
            int best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
            int best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
            int best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
            // ...
            int best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
        }
        else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
            if (my_queue.front().b_getter() > best_parameter_b) {
                // Found new best element since parameter B is second most important
                int best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
                int best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
                int best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
                // ...
                int best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
            }
            else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
                // ...
                // Many more checks
                // ...

                // Till last parameter is checked
                if (my_queue.front().z_getter() > best_parameter_z) {
                    int best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
                    int best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
                    int best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
                    // ...
                    int best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
                }
            }
        }

        my_queue.pop();
    }
};
```

The conditions are obviously oversimplified and there are actually less than 26 parameters, I'm using a-z just to generalize the problem.

Now I was obviously very displeased with this code and attempted to come up with some way to have the lines that update the parameters in one place. This is what I came up with:

```
void class_method() {

    std::queue<int> my_queue;
    // generation of many objects happens here

    // Now I want to find the best element and I store the values for deciding parameters
    // storing the object itself would be very inefficient as I care only about some key values
    int best_element_id = 0;
    int best_parameter_a = 0;
    int best_parameter_b = 0;
    // ...
    int best_parameter_z = 0;

    while (!my_queue.empty()) {
        if (my_queue.front().a_getter() > best_parameter_a) {
            // Found new best element since parameter A is most important
            goto new_best;
        }
        else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
            if (my_queue.front().b_getter() > best_parameter_b) {
                // Found new best element since parameter B is second most important
                goto new_best;
            }
            else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
                // ...
                // Many more checks
                // ...

                // Till last parameter is checked
                if (my_queue.front().z_getter() > best_parameter_z) {
                    goto new_best;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (false) {
            new_best:
            int best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
            int best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
            int best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
            // ...
            int best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
        }
        my_queue.pop();
    }
};
```

What other options do I have?

Would such usecase be considered okay? If it is, maybe there is a more elegant way to write that without the `if (false)` condition? I'm also aware that I couldve used the GOTO to jump back to the first condition evaluating to True but I'm not a big fan of jumping backwards in code so I assumed putting the condition `if (false)` at the end makes this *somewhat* more readable...

Last but not least, my IDE throws warnings because of the `if (false)` line, but I'm assuming the compiler will not optimize it away, right?

Comment: you missed something important, what does your code do? Currently, it looks very hypothetical

Comment: Yes, the "best object picking" part from the whole method is just a small part, but seemingly the ugliest one. A complete conditional mess and a lot of code copying. Therefore I'm wondering if this part specifically could be rewritten in a more efficient or simply a more elegant way.

Comment: I get it, but you should explain properly as to what your code does.

Comment: The thing is,  Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. all the `...` in your question indicate that.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain what this specific snipped of code does. The `...` in my code are there to avoid making my code example having 300 Lines of code or other lines of code that are in no way relevant to my question which is specifically about GOTO usage.

Comment: Ok so I went through all of the uses of `//...` and I found only two different implications by that comment - either it's to show that there are more parameters that could be represented by letters from a to z or more nested if loops that follow the same logic as the previous ones? I don't feel like I left anything important out or anything of relevance to the question.

Comment: The question is still very unclear, no idea what to code does, where the function belongs, whether it is a part of a class. Nothing at all :/

Comment: What the snippet does has been already added to the question to increase clarity. What class it belongs to and what happens after the best object has been picked is in no way or form relevant to my question whether it's an acceptables use of GOTO? I'm sorry but I don't see how knowing what class it's from would change your answer whether jumping to an `if (false)` block is an okay practice or not? I could obviously add all of that information to the post but I left it out intentionally to begin with because I don't see how it could influence an answer to any of my questions

Comment: Yes, that's where the problem is :), I suggest you don't take my word on it and read  [ask]. Only providing a " snippet " is not enough context for a proper review of your code.

Comment: Also read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652)" If your question contains stub code, then there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works. "

Comment: As hypothetical code, this does look off topic. Are you aware of `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: No, I was not aware of it, now that I'm reading about it, it looks like a very good alternative to the messy code that I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> GOTO should normally be avoided in production code and it tends to be unreadable for others

Readability isn’t just “for others”, it’s *for you*, as well.

That said, if a `goto` makes code more easily readable, go for it. It’s just that these situations are exceedingly rare in C++. And your code isn’t one of them. In fact, your `goto` solution, where the label is nested in an `if (false)`, is primarily *cryptic*.

As it stands, the control flow in your code is obfuscated. This isn’t just due to the `goto`, but the `goto` certainly doesn’t help (and in fact obfuscating control flow is precisely the quality that makes `goto` so controversial).

Your code also contains errors, which are hard to spot. For instance, you test `my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a` *twice*. The second time is almost certainly intended to test `b_getter() == best_parameter_b`. Such errors get more likely with complex, deeply nested code flow.

It’s hard to give concrete recommendations without concrete code. Fundamentally, the purpose of your `goto` seems to be to skip a loop iteration when some conditions are not met. You’d usually use `continue` for this. Except, ah, you have that extra unconditional `queue.pop()` at the very end.

One straightforward solution is to replace `if (false)` with `if (update)`, and replace the `goto`s with `update = true;`. That makes the intent immediately more explicit, and thus the code more readable.

But I would be tempted to rewrite the logic completely, and in such a way that we can use `continue` inside a `for` loop here. The rewrite isn’t straightforward, since it requires not only inverting all your conditions inside the loop, but also restructuring the *flow* of the conditional statements.

```
for (; not my_queue.empty(); my_queue.pop()) {
    if (my_queue.front().a_getter() < best_parameter_a) {
        continue;
    }
    if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
        if (my_queue.front().b_getter() < best_parameter_b) {
            continue;
        }
        if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
            // ...
            // Many more checks
            // ...

            // Till last parameter is checked
            if (my_queue.front().z_getter() <= best_parameter_z) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
    int best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
    int best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
    // ...
    int best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
}
```

But this is still deeply nested and, as mentioned, that makes it unreadable and error-prone. The fact that you’re testing a large number of hard-coded parameters is a rancid code smell. When squinting, the whole code looks like it’s trying to establish a lexicographical between two vectors of parameters. So your code should really *express that*, using appropriate data structures and operator overloading:

```
while (not my_queue.empty()) {
    if (best_parameter < my_queue.front()) {
        best_parameter = my_queue.front();
    }
    my_queue.pop();
}
```

There.

This code isn’t (just) superior because it doesn’t require `goto`. It’s superior because it’s 90% shorter, has no deep nesting, and *directly expresses the intent*.

Comment: Ah, very insightful, the fact that I wrote `my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a` twice was indeed an error. The for loop solution is very neat, I did not consider using for loops like that. The solution with appropriate data structures and operator overloading definetly beats everything else on readability though.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, using GOTO is totally acceptable. But regarding your example, your code looks not very optimized in the first place.

Nevertheless, some tips for you when using GOTO.

You should use labels in the most possible upper scope (if possible, function scope). Labels should be written in capital letters. You should never jump over any declaration of any kind. Write a label at the same column like the function scope brackets, to enhance readability. Don't use arbitrary constructs like `if(false)`, if you are using GOTO anyway, you might as well use it also in its full glory.

For example:

```
while (!my_queue.empty()) {
    int best_element_id;
    int best_parameter_a;
    int best_parameter_b;
    // ...
    int best_parameter_z;
    
    if (my_queue.front().a_getter() > best_parameter_a) {
        // Found new best element since parameter A is most important
        goto NEW_BEST;
    }
    else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
        if (my_queue.front().b_getter() > best_parameter_b) {
            // Found new best element since parameter B is second most important
            goto NEW_BEST;
        }
        else if (my_queue.front().a_getter() == best_parameter_a) {
            // ...
            // Many more checks
            // ...

            // Till last parameter is checked
            if (my_queue.front().z_getter() > best_parameter_z) {
                goto NEW_BEST;
            }
        }
    }
    goto NO_NEW_BEST;
    
NEW_BEST:
    best_element_id = my_queue.front().id_getter();
    best_parameter_a = my_queue.front().a_getter();
    best_parameter_b = my_queue.front().b_getter();
    // ...
    best_parameter_z = my_queue.front().z_getter();
    
NO_NEW_BEST:
    my_queue.pop();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I knew there had to be a cleaner way instead of using `if (false)"... Aside from the code not being optimized in the first place, your code does look a lot more readable.

Comment: By the way, to ensure my statement, _"You should use labels in the most possible upper scope (if possible, function scope)."_, I would write the while-loop as a GOTO-loop. Because using a GOTO-statement within a while-loop hurts a structured text while-loop ^^. What you are actually looking for is an interleaving loop (An interleaving loop consists out of 2 or more loops, looping into each other.), a tool which structured texts doesn't provides, the only way is a GOTO. GOTO is even the most precise way to accomplish this task, any other method is just a work around.